# Zkoss grid paging customization

Tags: java, jsp, zk

I'm trying to build a grid with a pagination, but I'd like to change the text which appears before/after the numbers.

```
<grid sclass="myTable" mold="paging" pageSize="1" >
...
</grid>
//Under the table now there is a pagination
```

Now its something like "Previous" and "Next". How can I use images here instead?

Or if its not possible could someone show me a tutorial on how to do this with a custom renderer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to replace the element or use CSS3 to put some text with the element.
For example,

```
<style>
.myTable .z-paging-text:before {
    content: 'before';
}
.myTable .z-paging-text:after {
    content: 'after';
}
</style>
```